# How can I reuse exceptions handling in a Widget or Flutter Screen with asynchronous requests?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, flutter-provider

This is what I'm currently trying to achieve:

I want to display different error messages using the `intl` package, which uses the `BuildContext` to know the user language. Therefore I want to handle in the Widget the exceptions so that I can show them in the appropriate language.

I have implemented my code as follows:

- Widget/Screen where I display everything.
- A provider which manages the state.
- A service which is in charge of making the request.
- A set of custom exceptions to select the error messages I want to display.

My problem is that if I try to reuse the exceptions by building a future where I catch the exceptions, the original functions that made the query get executed anyway.

To illustrate the issue I wrote a minimal example with all this components in place:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart' as http;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

///
/// CUSTOM EXCEPTION
///
class CustomTimeoutException implements Exception {}

///
/// SERVICE
///
class DemoService {
  /// Return the client with a set timeout
  http.IOClient _client() {
    final ioClient = HttpClient();
    ioClient.connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 5);
    return http.IOClient(ioClient);
  }

  /// Fetch all items of the inventory
  Future<dynamic> fetchAllItems() async {
    const String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8081";

    http.Response response;
    try {
      response = await _client().get(Uri.parse(url));
    } on SocketException {
      print("Timeout reaching the server");
      throw CustomTimeoutException();
    }

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      print("Error fetching all data. ${response.statusCode}");
      throw Exception("Error trying to fetch. (${response.statusCode})");
    }

    return response.body;
  }
}

///
/// PROVIDER
///
class DemoProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<String> _items = [];
  bool _isLoading = false;

  List<String> get items => _items;
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  /// Download the list of items
  Future<void> fetchAllItems(bool refresh) async {
    // Fetch
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      final response = await DemoService().fetchAllItems();

      _items.addAll(response['items']);
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } on CustomTimeoutException {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}

///
/// MAIN WIDGET
///
class DemoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DemoWidget> createState() => _DemoWidgetState();
}

class _DemoWidgetState extends State<DemoWidget> {
  String? _error;
  void _onTimeOutError(dynamic _) {
    setState(() {
      _error =
          "There was a timeout :( ${_.toString()}"; // TODO: Get translation from context
    });
  }

  Future<void> _fetchAllItems(bool refresh) async {
    setState(() {
      _error = null;
    });
    return context
        .read<DemoProvider>()
        .fetchAllItems(refresh)
        .catchError(_onTimeOutError, test: (e) => e is CustomTimeoutException);
  }

  void _onPressed() {
    print("Test");
    _fetchAllItems(true).then(
      (value) => print("Do something after fetch"),
    );
  }

  void _onPressed2() {
    print("Test2");
    _fetchAllItems(true).then(
      (value) => print("Do another thing after fetch"),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<DemoProvider>(builder: (ctx, provider, _) {
      return provider.isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _onPressed,
                    child: const Text("Test"),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _onPressed2,
                    child: const Text("Test2"),
                  ),
                  if (_error != null) Text(_error!)
                ],
              ),
            );
    });
  }
}

///
/// APP
///
class DemoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<DemoApp> createState() => _DemoApp();
}

class _DemoApp extends State<DemoApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => DemoProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        title: "Demo Application",
        home: Scaffold(
          body: DemoWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(DemoApp());
}
```

I want to be able to reuse the exception handling in different functions (`_onPress` and `onPress1`). But the `then` gets always executed anyway.

```
I/flutter (15240): Test
I/flutter (15240): Timeout reaching the server
I/flutter (15240): Do something after fetch
```

I want the last print (`.then((value) => print("Do another thing after fetch"))`) to be only executed if the exception was not caught.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your problem correctly..

In your case, the 'catchError()' method is only responsible for handling the 'CustomTimeoutException' exception and does not rethrow any other errors.

A possible solution is to modify the fetchAllItems method in your DemoProvider class to catch all exceptions and rethrow only the CustomTimeoutException exception. You can then use the catchError() method in your _fetchAllItems method to handle all other exceptions and update the _error variable accordingly.

```
Future<void> fetchAllItems(bool refresh) async {
    // Fetch
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      final response = await DemoService().fetchAllItems();

      _items.addAll(response['items']);
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is CustomTimeoutException) {
        _isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
        rethrow;
      } else {
        throw e;
      }
    }
  }
```

And in your DemoWidget :

```
Future<void> _fetchAllItems(bool refresh) async {
    setState(() {
      _error = null;
    });
    return context
        .read<DemoProvider>()
        .fetchAllItems(refresh)
        .catchError((e) {
      _onError(e);
      if (e is CustomTimeoutException) {
        throw e;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have other exceptions other that CutomTimeoutException. But for simplicity I just wrote one. My problem is that I want to catch multiple of those, and then in case nothing was catched execute some code. But with the example I provided both `_onClick`'s functions get executed after handling the exception. I want to catch something but don't continue with the code in case it had an exception,